How to disable a Paragraphs bundle for only _new_ content?
We have a Paragraphs bundle that we’re sending into semi-retirement.  We’d like to prevent new content from being created with it.  We want to leave existing content as-is.  How can we prevent this bundle from appearing in the “Add Component” dialogue?
I don’t see a Paragraphs hook like hook_paragraphs_bundles_alter().  Is there a more general “entity” hook that I can use?
Next I considered a form alter, but AFAICT these buttons are floating all by themselves and not within a form HTML element.
Paragraphs has a submodule called "Paragraphs Type Permissions" - you could enable it and then restrict creation access. But adding a new subsystem for just this seems like overkill.
We could use JS.  But I’d love to convince this client to use a better widget with screenshots and descriptions.  I want this change to be robust enough to handle that without tweaking.
['field_component_supplementary_grid_add_more', 'field_component_intro_grid_add_more'].forEach((buttonName) => {    
  console.log(buttonName);
  document.getElementsByName(buttonName).forEach((node) => node.remove()); 
});


The “subsystem” is just an implementation of APIs you’ll otherwise have to implement yourself, isn’t it? Did you check the sub module to see what approach it takes?

Apparently I might be able to use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create_access().  I'll report back when this ticket enters a sprint.

You could restrict access to this component by the hook: "hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create_access" in the .module file of a custom module.
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create_access().
 */
function YOUR_CUSTOM_MODULE_paragraph_create_access(AccountInterface $account, array $context, $entity_bundle) {
  // Hide obsolete components, you can continue editing existing components.
  if ($entity_bundle === 'grid') {
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
}

